# Is Mathematica 10 color managed?

Tags: color, image, rendering

With [`ColorProfileData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorProfileData.html) *Mathematica* 10 can handle device-dependent color spaces. However images with embedded color profiles, e.g. `sRGB`, are rendered and displayed differently from Adobe Photoshop (which, of course, supports color management).  Does *Mathematica* 10 support ICC color profiles for rendering images?

Comment: Does the second of the "Basic Examples" in [`format/ICC`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/ICC.html#279032536) help at all?  (Forgive me, I'm out of my depth here.)

Comment: @Robinaut Are you saying that MMA and Photoshop use different default rendering intents to convert between colourspaces? I don't fully understand what you mean by "support".

Comment: Basically, yes. Put differently, does Mathematica use any monitor color profiles to render and display color images? To my knowledge, only few programms (like Photoshop etc.) support color managment. Most programms ingore device-dependent color profiles, e.g. most browsers, see http://cameratico.com/tools/web-browser-color-management-test/ for details