# Imported macOS screenshots display differently

Tags: color, image, display

When I take a screenshot in macOS (cmd-shift-4) and then import into a notebook, the colors tend to look washed out. Can anyone reproduce this behavior, and is there a workaround?

For example let's take a screenshot of a green disk:

[image]

This image can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrxlwj2qeuh8cug/Screen%20Shot%202022-05-25%20at%208.14.04%20AM.zip?dl=0).

Now let's import the screenshot and compare to what we see in Preview:

[image]

We can look at the image data to see it's indeed not `RGBColor[0, 1, 0, 1]`:

```
img = Import["/Users/ghurst/Dropbox/Screenshots/Screen Shot 2022-05-25 at 8.14.04 AM.png"];

ImageData[img][[500, 500]]
```

> ```
> {0.454902, 0.988235, 0.298039, 1.}
> ```

Lastly, macOS's [Digital Color Meter](https://support.apple.com/guide/digital-color-meter/welcome/mac) shows a difference:

[image]

---

It seems to be related to the image's color profile. Converting `Green` to the images profile gives roughly the same value as `ImageData`:

```
profile = Import["/Users/ghurst/Dropbox/Screenshots/Screen Shot 2022-05-25 at 8.14.04 AM.png", "ColorProfileData"];

ColorConvert[Green, profile]
```

> ```
> RGBColor[0.458625, 0.984878, 0.298528]
> ```

---

Possibly the same question as here: [Is Mathematica 10 color managed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56946/is-mathematica-10-color-managed)

Comment: You can see with exiftool.exe that it has Display P3 color profile. That is sRGB transfer function, but primaries and white point are different with sRGB, those are P3-D65. On windows you have to color manage everything, while on macos OS does it. The display in Safari of that png would be correct.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a valid workaround, but it does change the data.

Note that this works in 12.3 but not 13.0!

```
file = "/Users/ghurst/Dropbox/Screenshots/Screen Shot 2022-05-25 at 8.14.04 AM.png";

img = Import[file];

profile = Import[file, "ColorProfileData"];

{img, ColorConvert[img, profile -> "RGB"]}
```

[image]

---

In version 13.0 the following seems to be a valid workaround. I was surprised to see the (new in 13) `WhitePoint` option have no effect.

```
ColorConvert[ColorConvert[img, profile -> "XYZ"], "RGB"]
```